# Would the sum of an infinite series be finite if there were gaps between each numbers that increased until reaching infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

If you were to have a series:

1+1+2+4+7+11+16+22...

Where the gap between the numbers increased by one every time, wouldn't this gap eventually become infinite? Once it was, what would happen? Would it be possible to sum this series because although it is infinite, it has the infinite gap as well, so would this infinite gap stop the infinite series? And if it did, would the infinite series even be considered infinite, although it would have to be infinite in order for the gap to reach infinity.

Comment: No, according to the ratio test

Comment: The terms don't go to $0$ so the series clearly diverges.  Even in a series like $\sum n^2$ the gaps grow arbitrarily large.

Comment: No, there would never be an infinite gap, any more than you eventually count up to infinity starting $1,2,3,\dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. At any point the gap is finite. The gap will never become infinite.

Comment: But because the series is infinite, wouldn't that imply that the gap grows infinitely?

Comment: The gap gets bigger and bigger, yes, but you never get an infnite gap. You can keep adding one to a number:1,2,3,... but you will never reach infinity, for infinity is not a natural number. Rather, there are infinitely finite numbers.... which is exactly why you won't get 'past' those finite numbers and 'reach' infinity.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the help I was just curious about the topic, I haven't been able to look into series much yet.

Comment: @LincolnFuller You write down as many terms as you like in the series, the individual terms increase beyond any limit and the gaps between successive terms also increase beyond any limit. But this does not mean you can actually write down an infinite number of terms, neither does the gap become infinite. When mathematicians talk about the sum of an infinite convergent series, the sum is arrived at through a limiting process. You don't actually add up an infinite number of terms.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are 2 infinite ladders which you & I have to climb. You climb 1 step and shout, "I have reached my first position!" Now you climb 2 **more** steps and shout "I have reached my third location!" Then you climb 3 **more** steps and shout "I have reached my sixth location!" and so on..
Doing so, you generate a series 1,3,6,10... which corresponds to the step of ladder you are on.
I hear all your shouts, forever and climb on my ladder steps which are equal to the location number which you shout .You wait till I have climbed the steps, and then we climb again. I And you climb , forever.
Hence, given enough time, I will hear you say any number that exist in the number system, no matter however large.
The point where I am on the ladder is reached by adding all terms of the series you shout. Which then implies that the series can be summed. No matter how far along the ladder you go. 
The crux is that "gap increases to infinity " means no matter how large a number you give me , I can show you a point in my series after which the gap will always be larger than the number you gave me. It does not mean gap becomes infinity.(In our example, it cannot be that the number of steps that we have to take **at any step** of the above process is infinite.
)